# Quadratic extension with Galois group semidirect product

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, semidirect-product

Let $K$ be a quadratic extension and let $F/K$ be an abelian Galois extension with Galois group $H=Gal(F/K)$. Assume that $F/\mathbb Q$ is Galois with Galois group given by the semidirect product $Gal(F/\mathbb Q)\simeq Gal(K/\mathbb Q)\ltimes H$, where the generator $\tau$ of the quotient $G/H\simeq Gal(K/\mathbb Q)$ of $G$ acts on the subgroup $H$ of $G$ by $g\mapsto \tilde{\tau}g\tilde{\tau}^{-1}$, and $\tilde{\tau}$ is any lift of $\tau$ to $G$. Show that if a prime $l$ of $\mathbb Q$ is inert in $K$, then it splits completely in $F$.

The sense is that the unique prime ideal $(l)=l\mathcal{O}_K$ of $K$ above $l$ splits completely in $F$.

I have no idea how to work with this problem. Some ideas?

Comment: I don't see why $(\ell)$ couldn't ramify? Consider for example $K=\Bbb{Q}(i)$, $F=K(\sqrt3)$ and $\ell=3$. Three is inert in $K/\Bbb{Q}$, but ramifies in $F/K$, no?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In your example, the Galois group is abelian.

Comment: @Offlaw I view a direct product as a special case of a semi-direct product. Of course, the OP should clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not true. Consider $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ and $F = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^6 - 3x^5 + x^4 + 3x^3 + x^2 - 3x + 1)$. Then, Gal$(F/\mathbb{Q}) = S_3$ and $5$ is ramified in $F$. But in $K$, it is inert.

See : [LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/6.0.214375.1)

Comment: Ok. I think the splitting field of $x^3-p$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ works the same way as long as $p$ is prime that is inert in the extension $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})/\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: That's an amazing example.